# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: getValidationMode

Tags: hibernate, maven

Hello Programming maestros,
I keep getting a runtime error

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: getValidationMode
```

Any ideas? I Have played around with Hibernate versions to see if perhaps an older version isn't compatible but nothing. Here is the full error stacktrace if it helps...

```
13:09:32,683  INFO Version:37 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
13:09:32,696  INFO Version:41 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
13:09:32,698  INFO Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
13:09:32,700  INFO Environment:342 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
13:09:32,720  INFO Ejb3Configuration:529 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: persistenceUnit
...]
<Oct 23, 2017 1:09:32 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1508778572215' for task '12'. Error is: 'java.lang.AbstractMethodError: getValidationMode'
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: getValidationMode
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:642)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: getValidationMode
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:642)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>
(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
><Oct 23, 2017 1:09:32 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'ip'.> 
<Oct 23, 2017 1:09:32 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: getValidationMode
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:642)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: getValidationMode
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:642)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

> 

Here are my pom.xml dependencies.

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tuckey - URL Rewrite -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- ROO dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${roo.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Security Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RC1</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RC1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RC1</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-js-resources</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Can anyone please PLEASE help?

Comment: Please post you pom.xml dependencies

Comment: I have updated the post and also posted the pom.xml

Comment: Where are you trying to deploy this application (which server)?